# How do I add header to each video in a row of videos?

Tags: html, layout

I have a row of videos like this:

```
<!-- Video #1 Start -->
<video width="30%" controls>
    <source src="videos/video1.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
    You should be seeing a video right now, but we have failed as webmasters.
</video>
<!-- Video #1 End -->

<!-- Video #2 Start -->
<video width="30%" controls>
    <source src="videos/video2.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
    You should be seeing a video right now, but we have failed as webmasters.
</video>
<!-- Video #2 End -->

<!-- Video #3 Start -->
<video width="30%" controls>
    <source src="videos/video3.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
    You should be seeing a video right now, but we have failed as webmasters.
</video>
<!-- Video #3 End -->
```

I am trying to add titles to each video so that the layout is like this:

```
Title #1    Title #2    Title #3
Video #1    Video #2    Video #3
```

Here is my best attempt, despite its failure:

```
<!-- Video #1 Start -->
<h3>Video #1</h3>
<video width="30%" controls>
    <source src="videos/video1.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
    You should be seeing a video right now, but we have failed as webmasters.
</video>
<!-- Video #1 End -->

<!-- Video #2 Start -->
<h3>Video #2</h3>
<video width="30%" controls>
    <source src="videos/video2.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
    You should be seeing a video right now, but we have failed as webmasters.
</video>
<!-- Video #2 End -->

<!-- Video #3 Start -->
<h3>Video #3</h3>
<video width="30%" controls>
    <source src="videos/video3.mp4"
            type="video/mp4">
    You should be seeing a video right now, but we have failed as webmasters.
</video>
<!-- Video #3 End -->
```

How can I add the title to each video while maintaining my desired layout?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted all previously code. here is a snippet that appears to be working, i have deleted the src attribute in order to make jsfiddle work.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/ue8e1004/

```
<h3 style="width: 30%;float:left;">Your title.</h3>
<h3 style="width: 30%;float:left;">Your title.</h3>
<h3 style="width: 30%;float:left;">Your title.</h3>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<!-- Video #1 Start -->

<video width="30%" controls>

    You should be seeing a video right now, but we have failed as webmasters.
</video>
<!-- Video #1 End -->

<!-- Video #2 Start -->

<video width="30%" controls>

    You should be seeing a video right now, but we have failed as webmasters.
</video>
<!-- Video #2 End -->

<!-- Video #3 Start -->

<video width="30%" controls>

    You should be seeing a video right now, but we have failed as webmasters.
</video>
```

Comment: You missing closing tags on the h3s, but it still doesnt work :(

Comment: Deleted all previous code and added a new snippet. Please check it out and sorry.